# Hiding element when scrolling choppy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header that I want to be hidden once you start scrolling into the content of my webpage. This is the code I used:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
    $("header").css({
      display: "none"
    });
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
    $("#msg").css({
      display: "none"
    });
  }
});
```

The header does disappear correctly however, when I start scrolling some of my other elements disappear temporarily and the page jumps around. When I scroll to the top the header is gone (like I want) and the other elements are in place like they should be. My other elements are also triggered to appear when scrolling using ScrollReveal so I don't know if this may be interfering somehow.

```
ScrollReveal().reveal(".glitch", {
  delay: 3000,
  easing: "ease-in"
});

ScrollReveal().reveal("header", {
  delay: 5000,
  easing: "ease-in"
});

ScrollReveal().reveal(".arrow", {
  delay: 7000,
  distance: "-50px",
  easing: "ease-in"
});

ScrollReveal().reveal("nav", {
  delay: 8000,
  easing: "ease-in"
});
```

Comment: Update: I just noticed the last section of my webpage is completely gone and my footer is floating and not at the very bottom.

Comment: Hi Nasya - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below an answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (click the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. ***Also note that you can upvote instead of (or in addition to) the checkmark, to reward answers that were also helpful.*** If no answer was helpful, please post your own answer and select it with the checkmark to close out the question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do to prevent that. Basically, the problem is related to the fact that you are re-hiding that div repeatedly, even after it is hidden - so many times, in fact, that you are "flooding" the browser.

### 1. Create a "state" variable

Create a variable that stores the current *visibility state* of the element, and only hide the div if the var says it hasn't yet been hidden:

```
var hdrVisible = true, msgVisible = true;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
    if (hdrVisible){
        $("header").hide();
        hdrVisible = false;
    }
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
    if (msgVisible){
        $("#msg").hide();
        msgVisible = false;
    }
  }
});
```

### 2. Use a Debouncer

Also, you should look into the [debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) plugin. It will allow you to limit the number of times that a function will fire.

---

The `window.scroll()` function fires many times per second - to see how many times, view this example:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
   let tmp = $(window).scrollTop();
   $('#msg').html(tmp);
});
```

```css
body{height:5000px;}
#msg{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;padding:15px;background:wheat;text-align:center;font-size:1.3rem;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg"></div>
```